# Search for an existing Marketing Cloud contact using REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I'm trying to search for a contact by contact key using the SFMC REST API but all I am getting is a HTTP 500. I am using a known contact ID.

Endpoint: (POST) https://www.exacttargetapis.com/contacts/v1/contacts/search

```
{
"conditionSet": {
    "operator": "And",
    "conditionSets": [],
    "conditions": [{
        "attribute": {
            "key": "Contact.Contact Key",
            "id": "",
            "isCustomerData": false
        },
            "operator": "Equals",
            "value": {
                "items": ["123"]
        }
    }]
}
```

I'm also getting a 500 when using other known attributes as well as trying different combinations of the fully qualified name of the attribute key and/or the ID. This data was obtained from https://www.exacttargetapis.com/contacts/v1/attributeSetDefinitions

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the quick closure but turns out it's due to the contact model being broken in one of the business units so something to bare in mind if anyone experiences the same issues.